# data is undefined in the controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display a date that I'm getting from a server, I'm able to retreive it and display it correctly in the service but in my controller it's undefined would you help me to get this fixed.
here is my service

```
function footerService($http,$filter) {
var dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
var statusDate = {};

statusDate.getStatusDate = function() {
    $http.get(_contextPath + "/getDate", {}).success(
            function(response) {
                console.log('response', response)
                statusDate.Date = $filter('date')(
                        new Date(response.Date), dateFormat);
                console.log('Date', statusDate.Date)
                return statusDate.Date;
            });
};
return statusDate;

};
```

and in my controller

```
function footerController($scope,footerService) {
$scope.myDate = footerService.getStatusDate();
console.log('$scope.myDate', $scope.myDate);
};
```

Comment: `footerService` is async, the moment you call it the value has not been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function footerService($http, $filter) {
    return {
        getStatusDate = function() {
            return $http.get(_contextPath + '/getDate', {});
        }
    };
}

function footerController($scope, footerService) {
    $scope.myDate;

    footerService.getStatusDate().then(function(response){
        $scope.myDate = response.data.Date;
    }).catch(function(response){
       //error 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$q.defer` :

```
function footerService($http,$filter) {
    var dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
    var statusDate = {};

    statusDate.getStatusDate = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(_contextPath + "/getDate", {}).success(
            function(response) {
                statusDate.Date = $filter('date')(
                        new Date(response.Date), dateFormat);
                deferred.resolve(statusDate.Date );
            });

       return deferred;
    };

  return statusDate;

};
```

And then:

```
footerService.getStatusDate()
.then(function(data) {
   $scope.myDate = data;
});
```

Comment: `$http` already returns a promise.  There is no need to form a promise of a promise.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK you are true, I just wanted to demonstrate the use of `$q`

Answer (score 0):

Using `$http` means using async Promises.
You can define what happens when the async call is successful using `then` :

```
footerService.getStatusDate()
.then(function(receivedDate) {
   $scope.myDate = receivedDate;
   console.log('$scope.myDate', $scope.myDate);
});
```

Plus don't forget the `return` in `getStatusDate` (`return $http.get...`).

More info about async Promises : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0):

In the service you need to return the promise from the $http request.

Try:

```
function footerService('$http', [$http]) {
    var statusDate = {};

    getStatusDate = function() {
        return $http.get(_contextPath + "/getDate", {})
    };
    return {
        getStatusDate: getStatusDate
    };

};
```

And your controller like this:

```
function footerController($scope,footerService) {
    footerService.getStatusDate().then(function(results) {
        $scope.myDate = results.data;
    });
    $scope.$watch(function() {return $scope.myDate;}, function() {
        console.log('$scope.myDate', $scope.myDate);
    });

};
```

And you would apply your filter logic in the .then() method in the controller.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work, because the footerService constructor returns getStatusDate. So if you call footerService(), it's not going to have a getStatusDate().

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fat fingered the API return for the service.

Comment: It's the same as the OP's API. I'm surprised they're not getting a JS error.

Answer (score 0):

Since .success(function(){}) is the callback so you can not return any value from there. The best solution for it to pass one successCallback from controller to getStatusDate and pass the expected response from .success(function(response){}) to successCallback. 
By doing this you will be able to get the service response in your controller.

### Code is attached below:

```
function footerService($http,$filter) {
  var dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
  var statusDate = {};

  statusDate.getStatusDate = function(successCallback) {
      $http.get(_contextPath + "/getDate", {}).success(
            function(response) {
                successCallback($filter('date')(new Date(response.Date), dateFormat));
            });
  };
  return statusDate;

};


function footerController($scope, footerService) {
     function successCallback(res) {
         $scope.myDate = res;
         console.log('$scope.myDate', $scope.myDate);   
     }

     footerService.getStatusDate(successCallback);
};
```